# How to switch Windows 10 icon text shadows on/off?

Tags: windows-10, themes, styles, desktop-icons

After a recent update icon titles on the Windows 10 desktop have shadows. Some users find the text harder to read with shadows.

Does anybody know how/where to switch them off?

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel, System, Advanced System Settings, Advanced, Performance Options, and scroll through the list. Turn off Drop Shadow and then close out, restart. I do this on my Windows 10 machines

You can also use Windows Classic theme with plain background.  I use a Blue background